# How to use JQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm studying jQuery mobile but I could not figure out why this code does not work at my script "tap". I have already seen a lot of time and I'm referring the code from jQuery. https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/

The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-alpha.1.min.css">

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

    $("#dsa").bind("tap",qq);
    function qq(event){
        $(event.target).css("background-color","#F0F");
        }
    </script>
    <div data-role="page" data-title="Tableau測試" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header">
        <p>從下方選單選擇一個想看的東西</P>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ol data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="20180615-0001.html" rel="external">20180615-0001</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.html" rel="external">test</a></li>
                <div><p id="dsa" style="background-color:#0F6">fnhdjiahgdifsaghui</p></div>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" id="foo">
        <p></P>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [link](https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/) you say you are referring, note the `$(function(){...});` notation you have omitted. It makes your functions when the document is ready. So, add it in `script` as follows:

```js
$(function(){
   $("#dsa").bind("tap",qq);

  function qq(event){
     $(event.target).css("background-color","#F0F");
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-alpha.1.min.css">

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload='init()'>

    <div data-role="page" data-title="Tableau測試" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header">
        <p>從下方選單選擇一個想看的東西</P>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ol data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="20180615-0001.html" rel="external">20180615-0001</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.html" rel="external">test</a></li>
                <div><p id="dsa" style="background-color:#0F6">fnhdjiahgdifsaghui</p></div>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" id="foo">
        <p></P>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank for your help a lot
but I dont know why you write "function" at Outermost
I will study javascript hard ，Thank you again

Comment: Welcome! It is used to guarantee that the document is loaded i.e. ready to manipulate. It has several notations and one is that I've used. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for more info.